# Jquery replace method broken in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I am calculating a padding offset from my css file with Jquery. I need it to be a integer value so I am removing the "px" part with the .replace() method.

```
//calculate left and right padding on element
var padding_offset = $('#projects_menu').css("padding").replace('px', '')* 2;
```

when I do an alert(padding_offset); in firefox it returns 0. In chrome, IE, Opera it returns the current offset minus the "px" part so in this case "20".

Is this just a bug with firefox? What is the workaround here?

Comment: replace returns a string, which you then multiply. technically, it should be NaN.

Comment: What part are you questioning? Firefox returning 0 from .css("padding"), or the replace method.

Comment: The real meat of the question is great and I would upvote it. However, the title is so misleading. Did you really think the problem was with `replace`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shorthand CSS properties are not supported. As stated at http://api.jquery.com/css/

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not
>   supported. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin,
>   use: $(elem).css('marginTop') and $(elem).css('marginRight'), and so
>   on.

Since margin, padding, border and so on can have different values aswell as different units for each "sub property" this is really logical.

Comment: This makes sense. It's weird then that it works in Chome, Opera then.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the integer before you can multiply it

```
var padding_offset = parseInt($('#projects_menu').css("padding").replace('px', ''), 10)* 2;
```

But `parseInt` already ignores `px` at the end of the string, so you don't need it

```
parseInt( $('#projects_menu').css("padding"), 10) * 2;
```

Combine this with AntonNiklasson's answer and you have your working code (assuming padding-top gives you what you need)

```
parseInt( $('#projects_menu').css("paddingTop"), 10) * 2;
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Kato, he pointed out that this won't work if you've set your properties as anything other than pixels. He's created a nice `jQuery` helper to convert between units https://github.com/Zenovations/spritemation/blob/master/src/jquery.unitconverter.js

Comment: Whattup Juanito! It gets even more fun once you add in the fact that the padding-right/left/etc can be in different units (pixels, percent, em). I ended up [writing a util](https://github.com/Zenovations/spritemation/blob/master/src/jquery.unitconverter.js) just to deal with conversions and comparisons.

Comment: @kato What's up man, hope life is treating you well. I did think about that, and wanted to write something to handle it, but that would just take way too much time, let me link to your lib from the answer